# Possible bug with scipy.optimize SHGO sobol: TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: scipy, typeerror, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize, shgo

I have been trying to perform some global optimization with [SciPy optimizer SHGO](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html)
and I've had issues with the sampling metod `'sobol'`. Specifically, I get an error of the type: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`.

The thing that makes me suspect it may be related with something wrong with the sampling method per se is that the error doesn't happen when I use `simplicial` as sampling method or a different (still constrained) optimization algorithm such as `SLSQP`.

Here's the code, I'm interested in understanding if someone else can reproduce this error.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la
import scipy as sc
import scipy.optimize as opt

print("numpy version: ", np.__version__)
print("scipy version: ", sc.__version__)

# d-dim Shannon entropy
def ShEntr(x):
    s=0
    for p_i in x:
        if p_i > 1e-16 and p_i < 1-1e-16:
            s = s - p_i*np.log2(p_i)
    return s

# Function to be optimized
def fun(y, k, g):
    p,c = y
    mat = [[p,c],[c,1-p]]
    return -ShEntr(la.eigvals(mat))   #- sign in front of it due to the fact that scipy.otimize is a minimization

# Optimization parameters
x0 = [0.5,0.2] # Starting point for SLSQP
boun = [(0,1),(0,1)] # Optimization parameters bounds
cons = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda y: y[0]-y[0]**2-y[1]**2}) # Optimization parameters constraints

## Optimization
# SLSQP
res = opt.minimize(fun, x0, (0.3,0.3), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, bounds=boun, options={'maxiter':10000})
print("SLSQP: ", -res.fun)
# SHGO: simplicial
res = opt.shgo(fun, bounds=boun, args=(0.3,0.3), n = 30, iters = 5, sampling_method = 'simplicial', constraints=cons)
print("SHGO simplicial: ", -res.fun)
# SHGO: sobol
res = opt.shgo(fun, bounds=boun, args=(0.3,0.3), n = 30, iters = 5, sampling_method = 'sobol', constraints=cons)
print("SHGO sobol: ", -res.fun)
```

And here's what I get

```
numpy version:  1.20.3
scipy version:  1.7.3
SLSQP:  0.9999999999999942
SHGO simplicial:  1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "... path /test.py", line 36, in <module>
    res = opt.shgo(fun, bounds=boun, args=(0.3,0.3), n = 30, iters = 5, sampling_method = 'sobol', constraints=cons)
  File "... path \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 419, in shgo
    shc.construct_complex()
  File "... path \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 733, in construct_complex
    self.iterate()
  File "... path \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 876, in iterate
    self.iterate_complex()
  File "... path \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 912, in iterate_delaunay
    self.sampled_surface(infty_cons_sampl=self.infty_cons_sampl)
  File "... path \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 1243, in sampled_surface
    self.fun_ref()
  File "... path \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 1356, in fun_ref
    if g(self.C[i, :], *self.args) < 0.0:
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

P.S.: I understand that the function `fun(y, k, g)` here doesn't need args `k` and `g`, but I just (over)simplified the original function I was using (that needs `k` and `g`) to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g(self.C[i, :], *self.args)` is how `scipy` is passing a search variable and the `args` tuple to your function.  I think your `fun(y,k,g)` is handling that fine.

But I think the error is in calling one of the constraint or boundary functions.  They all have to have the same signature - with a 2 term `args` that means 3 variables.

`if g(self.C[i, :], *self.args) < 0.0:` testing some function result against 0.0.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
After additional research I found out that this is actually an unsolved (yet) known bug of scipy SHGO, discussed for instance in issues [15514](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15514), [16506](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/16506), [17549](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17549) and [18235](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/18235) and is related to how the algorithm feeds the `args` to the function as you pointed out.

A workaround to this bug is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72810072/21921370): use a wrapper instead of `args`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I report the workaround as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72810072/21921370)

Instead of feeding `opt.shgo` with `fun` and `args=(k,g)` just define a new lambda function and feed it to `shgo`:

```
func = lambda x,a=a,b=b: fun(x,a,b)
res = opt.shgo(func, bounds=boun, n = 30, iters = 5, sampling_method = 'sobol', constraints=cons)
```